# Convert java.util.Calendar ISO 8601 format to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, calendar, timestamp

I have a date in ISO 8601 date format `2015-09-08T01:55:28Z`. I used this code to convert the ISO 8601 fate to a Calendar object:

```
Calendar cal = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2015-09-08T01:55:28Z");
```

and now I need to use the `cal.getTime()` to get my time, but I need to convert it to a `java.sql.Timestamp`. I tried to do this:

```
final Timestamp finalDate = (Timestamp) cal.getTime();
```

but I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
```

Ideas?

Comment: `new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime())`

Comment: bingo! worked! thank you man! you should make this an answer so I can up vote you,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the exception says: [`Calendar::getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) returns a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, not a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object. So you cannot cast it to a Timestamp object.

Use:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

And also consider to replace [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) with the new [Date & Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) introduced in Java SE 8.

Answer (score 6):

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461385/642706) by Puce is correct.

## java.time

The modern way in Java 8 and later is to use the new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar that have proven to be confusing and troublesome.

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline, a count of nanoseconds from first moment of 1970 in UTC. The class is able to parse strings such as yours that comply with the ISO 8601 format.

```
String input  = "2015-09-08T01:55:28Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
```

### Database via old `java.sql` types

From an Instant, we can get a [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) by calling the [`from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method newly added to this old class.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

We could combine all three lines into a one-liner, not that I recommend it (makes debugging more difficult).

```
 java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( Instant.parse( "2015-09-08T01:55:28Z" ) );
```

## Database via `java.time` types

As of [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170), a compliant [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) should be able to pass the java.time types via `getObject` and `setObject` on a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). If your driver does not, use the conversion methods for the old classes.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , instant );
```